# Experimenting with Mean Variance Analysis

Tags: microeconomics, expected-utility, risk-aversion, portfolio-theory

here with a question about mean-variance analysis and utility theory hope you can help me.

**First point**

My main objetive is to maximize the expected utility from portfolios given by $\sigma_p^2=\frac{C}{D}[u-\frac{A}{C}]^2+\frac{1}{C}$. You can see that the latter is the function for the minimum variance frontier, so $A,C,D$ are all scalars and $u$ is the objetive expected return.

The following Taylor series approximation of the expected utility function around $(1+E(r))$ depends only on mean and variance, if the utility function is quadratic or asset returns are normally distributed

$$
\begin{align}
E\left[U(1+r)\right]&\approx U(1+\mu)+\frac{1}{2}U''(1+\mu)\sigma^2\\
\end{align}
$$

I assume that returns are normally distributed, and set my utility function as function $\frac{(1+r)^{(1-\gamma)}}{(1- \gamma)},\gamma>1$.

By the Taylor series approximation, and plugging the minimum variance function, I would then have

$$
\begin{align}
E\left[U(1+r)\right]&\approx\frac{(1+u)^{(1-\gamma)}}{(1-\gamma)}-[\dfrac{\gamma(1+u)^{-\gamma-1}}{2}\cdot\frac{C}{D}[u-\frac{A}{C}]^2+\frac{1}{C}]\\
\end{align}
$$

To find a local maximum, I would differentiate the above function and equate it to 0, as a necessary condition first orden condition, so $\frac{dE\left[U(u)\right]}{du}=0$.

Up to this point my question is really if I am allowed to do this ?

**Second Point**

If I am, then my next question is, how can I explain the effects of the risk free asset on the optimum value. By adding the risk free asset my optimum utility is raised, to me it seems normal as this new minimum variance frontier gives less variance for the same level of return, this is, in contrast with the first example, so $\frac{(u-rf)^2}{H}<\frac{C}{D}[u-\frac{A}{C}]^2+\frac{1}{C}$ for all $u$ excluding the tangent portfolio. The thing I don't understand is that for the same utility function, when I maximize expected utility with the new minimum variance function, I get a higher utility value, but also my expected objetive return is higher, this kind of makes sense if somehow I could explain this behavior by a risk aversion measure, such as the Arrow-Pratt risk premium. Then again, I don't know where I could apply it, so that I can calculate exactly the change in the optimum value when considering a risk free asset and when not considering it. I add some of my results, hope it becomes clearer

[image: Results of given different risk aversion parameters]

my minimum variance function scalars are $A=9.75, B=0.176,C=1072,D=9.38,H=B-2Arf+rf^2C$, $rf=.0017$

$$

Lastly, just to be clear with the last point, I wish to model the change in the optimum value when adding a risk free asset. So for example, for $\gamma=3$ I would like to explain analytically going from -.4775 to -.4727 when adding the risk free asset.

Please help me ! Thanks !!!